# Convert a number in base B to binary

Tags: string, binary, base-conversion

I have a very large string (around 1000 characters) and its represented in base B.

Whats the best way to convert it to binary representation since I can't use any arithmetic operators.

This is an interview practice question and I just want to clear up my basics about bit manipulation.

Comment: When you know the procedure to convert from base 10 to base 2 (binary base), then use the very same procedure to convert from any base to binary base.

Comment: yes i know the procedure, but i am just wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this conversion. For such a large string , each I'll have to iterate through each character and divide them by 2 for each division. Thus the complexity would be around n*logN where n is the length of the string and N is the number being represented